# Ayuda con error c# tipo AnonymousType

Tags: c#, wpf

Estoy tratando de enviar un dato a un textbox, para ello uso la funcion `MouseDoubleClick:`

```
private void DgvSeguimiento_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if(sender != null)
                {
                    DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;

                    if (grid != null && grid.SelectedItems != null && grid.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
                    {
                        DataGridRow gridRow = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(grid.SelectedItem) as DataGridRow;
                        DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)gridRow.Item;

                        txtRadicado.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Y en el `XAML:`

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgvSeguimiento" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                  MouseDoubleClick="DgvSeguimiento_MouseDoubleClick" AlternatingRowBackground="#66ffff" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="330" Margin="14,171,0,0" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="803">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="RADICADO" Binding="{Binding Path='Radicado'}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="FECHA" Binding="{Binding Path='FechaLog'}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="DOCUMENTO" Binding="{Binding Path='TipoDocumento'}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="SOPORTE" Binding="{Binding Path='TipoSoporte'}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="PROVEEDOR" Binding="{Binding Path='Remitente'}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="FACTURA #" Binding="{Binding Path='Asunto'}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="OBSERVACIONES" Binding="{Binding Path='Observaciones'}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>

        </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
```

> Edicion, anexo query del linq

```
private void llenargrid()
        {
            using (SICAP_PRUEBASEntities en = new SICAP_PRUEBASEntities())
            {
                var query = from fa in en.tblDocumental.ToList()
                            where fa.idEmpresa == 1 && fa.idDestinatario == Convert.ToInt32(SessionManager.UsuarioLogueado) && fa.EstadoG == "PENDIENTE"
                            select new { fa.Radicado };
                dgvSeguimiento.ItemsSource = query;
            }
        }
```

Pero cuando hago dobleclic me sale este error, que nunca me había topado, por ende no se que hacer, si alguien me puede orientar estare agradecido.

`Error:`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: como estas asignando el ItemsSource del datagrid ? o como asignas los datos

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Gracias por responder, el datagrid se llena con una consulta de linq `dgvSeguimiento.ItemsSource = query;`

Comment: podrias editar la pregunta y poner como armas esa query linq?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini Listo ya lo coloque

Answer (score 1):

Si analizas el mensaje veras que en el tipo anonimo esta indicando un tipo de dato por cada columna del grid, tienes 6 string y 1 datetime.

Si los datos los asignas desde una consulta `linq` esta es la que esta generando esa `entidad anonima`, no aplica el uso de `DataRowView` porque esto solo sirve si usas un `datatable`.

lo primero que aconsejaria seria que definas una clase

```
public class Documental
{
   public string Radicado {get,set;}
}
```

entonces usas este en el linq

```
 var query = from fa in en.tblDocumental
              where fa.idEmpresa == 1 && fa.idDestinatario == Convert.ToInt32(SessionManager.UsuarioLogueado) && fa.EstadoG == "PENDIENTE"
              select new Documental() { 
                 Radicado  = fa.Radicado 
              };
dgvSeguimiento.ItemsSource = query;
```

Entonces al seleccionar podrias usar

```
Documental doc = (Documental)gridRow.Item;
```

obtienes directamente la entidad

Nota: lo que no entendi es porque si el grid tiene 7 columnas solo defines una sola en el select del linq

Comment: Gracias lo modifique, pero al hacer dobleclic me salta este error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se permite 'EditItem' para esta vista.`

Comment: en que linea te marca lo del EditIem ?

Comment: Le puse un punto de interrupción en `Documental doc = (Documental)gridRow.Item;

                        txtRadicado.Text = doc.Radicado.ToString();` Pero no se alcanza a ejecutar una vez hago doble clic me salta el `System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se permite 'EditItem' para esta vista.`

Comment: podrias poner un breakpoint mucho antes, al inicio del evento para ver si ingresa

Comment: Probe con varios, no importa donde lo coloque, si hago dobleclic me salta el error, que podria ser?

Comment: pero si vuelves al codigo que tenia antes, esto no ocurria? algo adicional se debio haber cambiado para qe no ingrese al evento

Comment: Reemplace este fragmento `DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)gridRow.Item;` por `Documental doc = (Documental)gridRow.Item;` y en el linq lo modifique con tu ejemplo esos fueron los cambios y la nueva clase que se creo

Comment: Para ambos ejemplos le puse al grid `IsReadOnly="True"` y con eso evite que se fuera al error que te contaba

Comment: ahh bien, se ve que estaba queriendo ingresar en modo edicion al seleccionar

Answer (score 0):

Tu DataGrid está usando como origen una colección de objetos, por lo tanto si lo que quieres es que en el TextBox aparezca un dato del objeto al que le diste DobleClick es tan simple como esto:

```
private void DgvSeguimiento_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        SICAP_PRUEBASEntities selected = (SICAP_PRUEBASEntities)grid.SelectedItem;
        txtRadicado.Text = selected.LA_PROPIEDAD_QUE_QUIERES_MOSTRAR;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Es más, lo puedes hacer en el XAML directo, bindeando la propiedad.

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=dgvSeguimiento, Path=SelectedItem.LA_PROPIEDAD_QUE_QUIERES_MOSTRAR}" x:Name="txtRadicado" Background="White"/>
```

Y listo, si en vez de llenar el DataGrid con una colección, lo hicieras con datos planos, como una consulta SQL entonces cambias la linea de llamada del objeto por esto:

```
private void DgvSeguimiento_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        DataRowView selected = (DataRowView)grid.SelectedItem;
        string value = selected.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
        txtRadicado.Text = value;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Solo le agregas que el selected no sea nulo y todo lo demás para que no falle.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, no se que pueda estar pasando con todo lo que intento me aparece `System.InvalidOperationException: 'No se permite 'EditItem' para esta vista.'` al momento de dar dobleclic

Comment: En qué línea lanza la excepción? (nota: corregido ultimo ejemplo que la asignación era 'value')

Comment: Para ambos ejemplos le puse al grid `IsReadOnly="True"` y con eso evite que se fuera al error que te contaba